# When to release a CCSpriteBatchNode once the animation is finished

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I am playing an animation and want to remove its batch node from the parent (CCLayer) as soon as the animation finishes playing. I am running it as a CCsequence so I have function named **animationFinished** which get called  when it finishes playing. But I can't remove batch node  from parent in this function as it get released and don't have any other retain. So game crashes, As it is still being used by the engine.

So basically at what event I can release my batch node. If i don't do so , then it will be added again and again to the CClayer.Please see code below

```
void GameLayer::playAnimation(const AnimationFileAndTypeInfo &powerFileInfo,float placeAtScreenWidthRatio,float placeAtScreenHeightRatio){

  std::string firstFrame,frameName,plist,plistPng;    

  plist=powerFileInfo.animFileInfo.plist;
    plistPng=powerFileInfo.animFileInfo.plistPng;
    firstFrame=powerFileInfo.animFileInfo.firstFrame;
    frameName=powerFileInfo.animFileInfo.frameName;

    // generic animation play code
    CCSpriteFrameCache *animCache = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache();
    animCache->addSpriteFramesWithFile(plist.c_str());

    _animPlayBatchNode = CCSpriteBatchNode::create(plistPng.c_str(), 100);
    this->addChild(_animPlayBatchNode,kForeground+1);

    short numberOfFrames=getPlistFramesCount(plist.c_str(),"frames");// plist is the full name with postfix .plist

    CCArray *spriteframes = CCArray::createWithCapacity(numberOfFrames);
    spriteframes->retain();

    _animPlayFirstSprite = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName(firstFrame.c_str());// with postfix .png
    _animPlayBatchNode->addChild(_animPlayFirstSprite,kForeground+1);
    _animPlayFirstSprite->setPosition(ccp(_screenSize.width*placeAtScreenWidthRatio, _screenSize.height*placeAtScreenHeightRatio));

    for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfFrames; i++)
    {
        char szName[50] = {0};
        sprintf(szName, "%s%i.png",frameName.c_str(),i);
        CCSpriteFrame* frame = animCache->spriteFrameByName(szName);
        spriteframes->addObject(frame);
    }

    CCAnimation *animation = CCAnimation::createWithSpriteFrames(spriteframes,0.05f);
    animation->retain();
    animation->setDelayPerUnit(0.08f);// 0.05f

    CCSequence *seq=CCSequence::createWithTwoActions(CCAnimate::create(animation), CCCallFuncO::create(animation,callfuncO_selector(GameLayer::animationFinished),(CCObject*)_animPlayBatchNode));

    _animPlayFirstSprite->runAction(seq);

    spriteframes->release();
    animation->release();

}
void GameLayer::animationFinished(CCObject *sender){

CCSpriteBatchNode *animBatchNode = (CCSpriteBatchNode*) sender;
animBatchNode->removeAllChildrenWithCleanup(true);
_isAnimationAlreadyPlaying=false;

//   animBatchNode->removeFromParent() , crashes if I do this

}
```

Comment: the use of a batch node here seems pointless because you only add a single sprite to it, for batch drawing to provide any benefit you'd have to have at least two sprites in the batch node. Batch nodes have nothing to do with /provide no benefit to playing animations (a common misconception).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Adding _animPlayFirstSprite directly to the CCLayer, works like charm and it also solved my problem as Now I can remove the _animPlayFirstSprite from animationFinished.